# Deploy SP 2010 WebParts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have build a webpart as a .dll file. It is already installed in my production environment, but I've made small changes to it. Would it suffice to uninstall the old .dll from the GAC and install the new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your web part does not require any other resources that have been changed, then you can simple copy the updated assembly in the GAC. Which is not the "nice" way of course, but it works.

Things to keep in mind:

- The application pool of the web application has to be recycled.
- The dll has to be deployed in the GAC on every front end server.

Why don't you go the SharePoint way and create a solution file (WSP)? This way you get a clean install and you don't have to bother with multiple servers, etc.